# I want to develop an object where the time field input must match the system date and time.Can anyone help?

Tags: validation-rule, system

I am working to create an object, where I will have date- time custom field. I want the input of this field to match with the system date and time. I have tried applying a validation rule, where this date-time custom field should be equal to Now(), but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

i Wrote following validation rule and its working fine for me:

```
NOT( 
        YEAR(DATEVALUE(dt1__c)) =  YEAR(DATEVALUE(now() ) )  
        &&
        MONTH(DATEVALUE(dt1__c)) =  MONTH( DATEVALUE( now() ))          
        &&
        DAY(DATEVALUE(dt1__c)) =  DAY(DATEVALUE( now() ))
        &&
        HOUR(TIMEVALUE(dt1__c)) =  HOUR( TIMENOW() ) 
        &&
        MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(dt1__c)) =  MINUTE(TIMENOW())
    )
```

If you want to apply this rule only for new records then use ISNEW()

I cant imagine the business login for this validation but i would have done this in workflow. let me know if it solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly.